# Create server-side Iframe in Razor Files

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, iframe, razor

I render some page from the server using Razor(.cshtml) syntax. The page has some HTML data which I render as:

```razor
<div class="html-body">
  @Html.Raw(HtmlText)
</div>
```

I have some external CSS loaded on this page, that quite frequently mess up my HTML content in `html-body` class. So I want to use an Iframe instead of div. But that doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to create Iframe directly from razor view? Or maybe some hack around to prevent any external loaded css files to exclude `html-body` class?

Thanks

EDIT:

I tried the following:

```razor
<iframe>
  @Html.Raw(HtmlText)
</iframe>
```

But it would just render as blank area.

Comment: "But that doesn't seem to work."...please show what you tried. Maybe it's nearly right.

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: Ah ok. An iframe is not like another element. You can't write content into it directly. You have to give it another URL to load from. So you need another MVC action method which will supply the HtmlText to load into the iFrame, and then you give the iframe the URL of that method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe explains how to use an iFrame, you can easily google this kind of documentation yourself to understand about an element

Answer (score 2):

You can use the srcdoc attribute, such as:

```
<iframe srcdoc="@Model.HTML"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

all u have to do is:
1- create a partial view (.cshtml) 
2- paste your all html source and css files to the file you named for example (IframeAction.cshtml) - don't forget to check true css, js patch. 
3- put the below code into your HomeController

```
        //in your HomeController

        public PartialViewResult IframeAction()
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
```

4- paste this below code in your destination page to call your html files(IframeAction.cshtml)

```
<iframe src="IframeAction/cshtml" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden; min-height:600px; height:100%; width:100%" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
```

5- the end.
now after running the destination page, you can see the IframeAction.cshtml in that page, in a div you set.